# Wrong colours in videos on JavaFX application (Gluon JavaFX port)

Tags: java, javafx, raspberry-pi, gstreamer, gluon-mobile

I need to run JavaFX application on Raspberry Pi. Application contains MediaPlayer objects.
Since Oracle's Java for ARM doesn't contain javafx package, I have installed Gluon JavaFX port for ARM. Unfortunately, all sample videos I play through application have swapped colours (seems that red and blue channels swapped). I tested with videos from different sources. On PC on Oracle's JRE application plays video with correct colours. [Sample video](https://www.sample-videos.com/video/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_1mb.mp4)
Since Gluon's JavaFX port uses `gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg`, I also tested GStreamer on Raspberry: `gst-launch-0.10 playbin uri=file:///sample.mp4`, however, video colours were correct, so it seems to be Gluon JavaFX port bug. Anyone could help to fix or find a workaround?

Sample class for testing:

```
public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Media pick = new Media(Paths.get("sample.mp4").toUri().toString());
        MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer(pick);

        MediaView mediaView = new MediaView(player);

        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(mediaView);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root,300,250);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

        player.play();
    }
}
```

EDIT: I've tried multiple other options to display video on java application. For others who need to display video on Raspberry, check out [VLCJ](https://github.com/caprica/vlcj) library. VLC displays correct colours and even works smoother than JavaFX MediaPlayer.